# Getting unexpected output in program

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

Here is code:

```
 String sql_1 = "select emp_id,password from regid";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql_1);

    while(rs.next())
    {

    if(((employee.equals(rs.getString("emp_id"))) && (password.equals(rs.getString("password"))))==true)
    {

//      String sql2="update regid set regid='"+Datastore.regIds.add(regId)+"' where emp_id='"+employee+"'";
//      st.executeUpdate(sql2);
        System.out.println("2> Employee Id : "+employee+" && Password : "+password);
        System.out.println("3> This employee "+employee+" exsists in the database and registration-password id will be Updated");

    //  resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<head>");
        out.print("<title>Policy Page</title>");
        out.print("<link rel='icon' href='../images/favicon.png'/>");
        out.print("</head>");
        String status = (String) req.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_STATUS);
        if (status != null)
        {
          out.print("Status :"+status);
        }
        List<String> devices = Datastore.getDevices();
        if (devices.isEmpty())
        {
          out.print("<h2>No  devices registered!</h2>");
        } 
        else
        {

         out.print("<h2>" + devices.size() + " device(s) registered!</h2>");
         out.print("<form name='form' method='POST' action='sendAll'>");
         out.print("<input type='text' name='policy'>");
         resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
         out.print("<input type='submit' value='Apply Policy'>");
         out.print("</form>");
//       System.out.println(HTTP_STATUS);
         System.out.println(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
         getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home").forward(req, resp);

        }
        out.print("</body></html>");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }

    else {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        System.out.println(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        System.out.println("4> This employee "+employee+" does not exsist in the database");            
    }

    }

//    rs.close();
    }
```

But I'm getting output like,but I'm putting the correct emp_id & password(still it's showing 4> + java.lang.illegalstateexception (don't know why ?? :( )):

```
1> Employee : P1 && Password : ppp
400
4> This employee P1 does not exsist in the database
2> Employee Id : P1 && Password : ppp
3> This employee P1 exsists in the database and registration-password id will be Updated
400
4> This employee P1 does not exsist in the database
```

any idea.....why it's happening ?

Comment: I hope this code never goes into production on any site I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you algorithm consists of:

1. Iterate through all employees
2. If employee matches ID/password, print 2>, else print 4>

So you'll have one `2>, 3>` output for the one that matches and all the others will give you the error 400.

Instead, you can iterate through all your employees (although it might be best to add a criteria to your SQL to narrow down the result set by password and employee ID), don't output an error unless you have exhausted all the results and did not find the matching one.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try {
    stmt = new PreparedStatement("select * from regis where emp_id=? and password=?");
    stmt.setString(1, employee);
    stmt.setString(2, password);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("2> Employee Id : "+employee+" && Password : "+password);
        System.out.println("3> This employee "+employee+" exsists in the database and                        
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<head>");
        out.print("<title>Policy Page</title>");
        out.print("<link rel='icon' href='../images/favicon.png'/>");
        out.print("</head>");
        String status = (String) req.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_STATUS);
        if (status != null)
        {
          out.print("Status :"+status);
        }
        List<String> devices = Datastore.getDevices();
        if (devices.isEmpty())
        {
          out.print("<h2>No  devices registered!</h2>");
        } 
        else
        {

         out.print("<h2>" + devices.size() + " device(s) registered!</h2>");
         out.print("<form name='form' method='POST' action='sendAll'>");
         out.print("<input type='text' name='policy'>");
         resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
         out.print("<input type='submit' value='Apply Policy'>");
         out.print("</form>");
//       System.out.println(HTTP_STATUS);
         System.out.println(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
         getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home").forward(req, resp);

        }
        out.print("</body></html>");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }

    else {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        System.out.println(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        System.out.println("4> This employee "+employee+" does not exsist in the database");            
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        stmt.close();
    } catch(Exception x) {}
}
```

Comment: added but didn't try to even compile it. It should give you enough.

Comment: Big thanks to you and c**p to me for my silly misconception.. but it's showing this error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Comment: while running the above code for true empid & password,unable to run the html page(which exists with in the If condition).... any idea.....how to do that..?

Comment: mprivat,one more thing is that,with this java code,the html part is not printed atall,I want to print that html part as well, you can take a look of this link I have posted :(   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671563/unable-to-set-the-value-for-running-the-java-file

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation isn't helping you. You're looping through *all* the employees, and comparing the username and password for each of them - so sometimes you'll get a match, and sometimes you won't.

There are *multiple* problems with this code:

- If you're only looking for one result, don't ask the database for all the rows! You should be passing query parameters and doing the filtering in the database. You can then work out whether or not you've got a match just by seeing whether there are any rows in the result or not.
- Your indentation makes it hard to see what's going on
- You're using huge numbers of unnecessary brackets and comparisons with `true`, e.g.

  ```
  if(((employee.equals(rs.getString("emp_id"))) && (password.equals(rs.getString("password"))))==true)
  ```

  would be better as

  ```
  if(employee.equals(rs.getString("emp_id") && 
     password.equals(rs.getString("password"))
  ```
- You appear to be using plain text passwords. **Don't do this.**

Comment: thanks for your input,... still it's printing 1> first then 4>...then 2> and 3>

Comment: @user1645434: Then you haven't made all the changes I've suggested... I doubt that you could have made them all in the 7 minutes between my answer and your comment, to be honest.

Comment: sorry to callling you in this way,but I have raise a question yet o get a proper answer,could you take a look of it,here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671563/unable-to-set-the-value-for-running-the-java-file

Comment: @user1645434: If you know it's not appropriate to leave a comment like that, just don't do it.