# Iterate through resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting unexpected output in program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622718/getting-unexpected-output-in-program)

To be frank,this question may be silly to ask, but I'm a novice in Java.
This is my Table `emp(name,id,address,date)`.

*Now I'm going to match a certain employee's corresponding password.*

```
String sql = "select emp_id,password from regid";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next()){
 // here will be iterate function using resultset,i guess
 // what should be the best logic to check the name and password...any inputs
 //in terms of code

if(if (employee.equals(rs.getString("emp_id")) && password.equals(rs.getString("password")))){
You are Mr. emp // in terms of code
}

else{
Who are You ?? //in terms of code
}
}
```

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have the basic idea. What's your exact problem, you need somebody to guide you what to do if you find a valid result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to create your query. So your parameterized query for the *PreparedStatement* would be something like this:

```
SELECT * from regid WHERE emp_id = ? AND password = ?
```

Plug in the paremeter values and execute  your statement. So it would be something like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
boolean validUser = false;

try{
    ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from regid WHERE emp_id = ? AND password = ?");
    ps.setString(1, [user_id_input]);
    ps.setString(2, [user_pw_input]);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    validUser = rs.next();
}finally{
    //Release your resources
}

if(validUser){
    //user is validated
}
```

As a side note, I would also suggest to validate your user's input before feeding it to your query.

Comment: //Release your resources -- what does it mean...in terms of code ?

Comment: That means you should close your ResultSet and your PreparedStatement:if (rs != null )rs.close(); if (ps!=null)ps.close();

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting the data for *all* employees and looking through them for a match.

Much better to have the database filter it:

```
select count(*)  from regid where emp_id = ? and password = ?
```

Then you only need to check if this returns 0 or 1.

Also, `password` is hopefully just a password hash.

Answer (score 2):

fetching all data from database make your application performance slow, So fire following query retrieve one record.

```
boolean status = false;
String emp_name = "";
String emp_password = "";
String sql = "select * from regid where emp_id='"+emp_id+"' AND password='"+password+"'";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
    if(emp_id.equals(rs.getString("emp_id")) && password.equals(rs.getString("password")))
    {
            // fetch employee data
            status = true;
    }
}
if(status)
{
        // login correct
}
else
{
        // login incorrect
}
```

Comment: //fetch all data.... in terms code what should be there?

Comment: there will be other data for employee like department_name so retrieve rs.getString("department_name");

Answer (score 1):

Query your database with `"select emp_id,password,... from regid where emp_id=? and password=?"`

Create a PreparedStatement and set emp_id and password. it will return you 1 row if emp_id and password match.

Comment: in terms of code .....how will match emp_id and password,...// could you..... :)

Comment: could give the an fair idea by writing the code ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually shouldn't be matching the password in the result set.  Your sql query should be something like

```
select emp_id from regid where password='userpassword'
```

where userpassword is the password you got from the screen your using