# Unable to set the value for running the java file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working in Google gcm application,and here I'm authenticating the app user by correct Id & password.Authentication is working properly.

*My I'm running this page by Run as -> Run on Server(Homeservlet.java),even for the correct employee and password,it's not showing the written jsp code(which is written in the if condition) and going to the else-part.*

In the eclipse console : I can see the employee name and it's password.But my question is how to set the values sothat when I will run this page it'll show that jsp page inside.

I'm using set parameter to set the value,but whenever I'm running this page in Tomcat server,it's showing `IllegalArgumentException`.I found it's quiet relevant because when I'm running the value's are not set.

Actually I want ,for the correct employee and corresponding password,...it'll show that jsp page; otherwise(i mean in else-part,it'll not)

```
public class HomeServlet extends BaseServlet {

      static final String ATTRIBUTE_STATUS = "status";
      private static final int HTTP_STATUS = 200;
    //  private static final String HTTP = "OK";


      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws IOException {


          PreparedStatement stmt = null;
          String employee=req.getParameter("employeeid"); //getting the value from app User
          String password=req.getParameter("password");  //corresponding password
          req.setAttribute(employee, employee);
          req.setAttribute(password, password);

          try {
              String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/apps";
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
              stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from regid where emp_id=? and password=?");
              stmt.setString(1, employee);
              stmt.setString(2, password);
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

              if(rs.next()) {
                  System.out.println("2> Employee Id : "+employee+" && Password : "+password);
                  System.out.println("3> This employee "+employee+" exsists in the database and will be there");      

                  resp.setContentType("text/html");
                  PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                  out.print("<html>");      //1> want to run this portion from here
                  out.print("<head>");
                  out.print("<title>Policy Page</title>");
                  out.print("<link rel='icon' href='../images/favicon.png'/>");
                  out.print("</head>");
                      out.print("<body>");
                  String status = (String) req.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_STATUS);
                  if (status != null)
                  {
                    out.print("Status : "+status);
                  }
                  List<String> devices = Datastore.getDevices();
                  if (devices.isEmpty())
                  {
                    out.print("<h2>No  devices registered!</h2>");
                  } 
                  else
                  {

                   out.print("<h2>" + devices.size() + " device(s) registered!</h2>");
                   out.print("<form name='form' method='POST' action='sendAll'>");
                   out.print("<input type='text' name='policy'>");
                   resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                   out.print("<input type='submit' value='Apply Policy'>");
                   out.print("</form>");
//                 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home").forward(req, resp);

                  }
                  out.print("</body></html>");   //2> to here
                  resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

              }


              else {                                      //else-part
                  resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
                  System.out.println(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
                  System.out.println("4> This employee "+employee+" does not exsist in the database");            
              }
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
              try {
                  stmt.close();
              } catch(Exception x) {}
          }


      }

      @Override
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
      }

    }
```

When the app user giving the id-password,the output in the console is:

```
2> Employee Id : P1 && Password : ppp
3> This employee P1 exsists in the database and will be there
```

but I'm running the page(run as->run on server-tomcat-6),it is showing this(instead of showing the jsp page)

```
HTTP Status 500
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot call setAttribute with a null name
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1431)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:50
```

any idea....... where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Could you add the output of the code when an employee loads that page? (filtering out pass ofc)

Answer (score 1):

2 things observed.

1)
Use

```
  req.setParameter("employee", employee);
   req.setParameter("password", password);
```

instead

```
  req.setAttribute(employee, employee);
  req.setAttribute(password, password);
```

2)

The next page you are showing is not a JSP. It is plain html created in servlet. 
The set content type is html.

If you want to display employee in html, 
you can write code like this,

```
 out.print("<body>");
 out.print("Welcome to this site Mr."+ employee);
```

If you still want to use the employee as a variable on that html, you have to embed Javascript in this page.

Comment: Same as the html creation. out.print("<javascript> var employeename="+employee +"</javascript>"); It is all that you are writing one html file in out.print of java servlet.

Comment: see,the benfit of using html is to send notification app users',but it seems there is some logical problem in my code,because whenever I'm running the page,it's going to else-part of my coding.